# Deletion of .ascx from programming causing session end

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a situation:

I upload user controls in a webapp and then load them when needed. Sometimes I dont want some of them. So I would want to DELETE them from my web application.

Here is the hierarchy where the controls are found.

/controls
/controls/uc/
/controls/uc/ctrl1/ctrl1.ascx  (with ctrl.ascx.cs)
/controls/uc/ctrl2/ctrl2.ascx  (with ctrl.ascx.cs)

Now from a delete.aspx, I have this code from where I pick the directory structure. and pick up the control directory "ctrl1(n)" and delete the directory with delete recursive.

When the deletion is over, I redirect the page using asp.net's redirect function. But as soon as the web page is redirected, the session is over and it asks me to login (as the only logged in users can delete the controls)

Why is that strange behaviour?

Remember, none of the code is found in app_code, all controls are put under website root as shown in the above.

Edit: Of course its not PRECOMPILED!

Any help?

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you, as a basic courtesy towards others...

Comment: @pOcHa, your answer was partly helpful just in the cause that you pointed me that deletion of directories is the cause but I was more interested in a solution. I have posted my answer on my own post see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I spent some time on solving this issue... It sounds like it may not be a solution but so far what I wanted has been achieved.

What I did was that I defined session state as "StateServer" and when I deleted the folders it restarts the application pool but the session remains alive. Since the application pool recycling is dependent upon several factors including the deletion of website's subfolders so you cant happen to stop it but can actually retain the session. If you delete folders, it wont cause loss of session but of course application will be restarted that you have to accept at any cost!

Anyway,

#### I used following config node in my web.config on my hosting:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer"  cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
</system.web>
```

#### And of course did this on my localhost:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer"  stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
</system.web>
```

**Note:** On localhost you must start your ASP.NET State Management Service

#### Summary:

1. You must define SessionState as StateServer or SqlServer in order to retain sessions. That is least you can do.
2. When developing such applications you **MUST** give them a way out to cope with the application restart cycles.
3. You must keep session variables as simple as possibles, do not put large objects or objects that depend upon many other objects. Serialization and deserialization takes lot of time to get them back and fro.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting classes in a running application (even a Website project) will most likely be causing an application pool recycle, and end session and everything else.
 
This whole idea of uploading user controls seems very strange.

For more information: [ASP.NET Case Study: Lost session variables and appdomain recycles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx)

Comment: Well basically its a customer CMS in which I develop new functionality in new controls and integrate them with existing components.

Comment: Magnus, i am not deleting classes, but the controls within the subfolders. The Application pool is restarted if the folders under a virtual directory are deleted. So in my case, i am deleting the folders with all controls whatsoever. The issue is that I need to create/delete subfolders when necessary, but do not want the application restart every now and then when I delete folders.

Answer (score 1):

Every change to directory structure (but not files, mind you) will cause app pool recycle - its dubious what you are doing, but just don't delete any folders (only files) and you should be ok.

Comment: Hmm... I noticed that though. But I guess it should not do that? Why App Pool recycles if the folders are removed?

Comment: @KMX it is something completely out of your hands, so you don't need to concern yourself about it at all (or google it if you absolutely must) - but just don't do it...

Comment: After spending many hours, i found what Magnus also shared in the link. I have gone through almost every corner and found everybody looking at Microsoft to provide a patch which they still have not done. I dont understand why would a folder be monitored rather the app folders? there must some underlying issue with that. I know they give the argument that they dont want to serve the deleted content but that should not be the case! if a file/content is deleted then the framework should be intelligent enough to determine and unload/remove the files pointers and so objects from the app domain.